# Installing R-packages in Azure Data Lake Analytics

Tags: r, u-sql

I have an issue with installing the below R-packages and reference them in an R-script I have encapsulated in a U-SQL-script. I succeeded in running a simple R-script in a U-SQL-job that required no special packages. Now I am trying to create an R-script that references dplyr, tdyr and reshape2. Therefore I have downloaded these three packages manually as both .zip and .tar.gz-files and uploaded them to my ADL-account. Example:

```
../usqlext/samples/R/dplyr_0.7.7.zip
```

The U-SQL  startes like this:

```
REFERENCE ASSEMBLY [ExtR];   //enable R extensions for the U-SQL Script

DEPLOY RESOURCE @"/usqlext/samples/R/dplyr_0.7.7.zip";
DEPLOY RESOURCE @"/usqlext/samples/R/reshape2_1.4.3.zip";
DEPLOY RESOURCE @"/usqlext/samples/R/tidyr_0.8.1.zip";
```

The R-script starts like this:

```
// declare the R script as a string variable and pass it as a parameter to the Reducer:
DECLARE @myRScript = @"
install.packages('dplyr_0.7.7.zip', repos = NULL) # installing package
unzip('dplyr_0.7.7.zip')
require(dplyr)

install.packages('tidyr_0.8.1.zip', repos = NULL) # installing package
unzip('tidyr_0.8.1.zip')
require(tidyr)

install.packages('reshape2_1.4.3.zip', repos = NULL) # installing package
unzip('reshape2_1.4.3.zip')
require(reshape2)
```

However I keep getting errors that indicate to me that the packages are still not successfully installed. Currently I get the following error message:

```
Unhandled exception from user code: "Error in function_list[[i]](value) : could not find function "group_by"
```

That error comes from the following piece of R-code:

```
longStandardized <- dataset %>%
    group_by(InstallationId) %>%
    mutate(stdConsumption = znorm(tmp)) %>%
    select(InstallationId, Hournumber, stdConsumption)
```

Hope that someone can see what I am missing.

Thanks
Jon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy way to do it, its download the file on datalake in directory: 
`usqlext\assembly\R\MRS.9.1.0.zip`

Them you unzip the file (on a machine without R installed) and execute R.exe on bin folder.

Now you can install all packages you want (with parameter dependencies = true)

```
install.packages('yourpackage', dependencies = TRUE)
```

Zip the folder again and replace the file on datalake by this you created.

Execute `RegisterAllAssemblies.USQL` again, and your package will be available for you!

```
library('yourpackage')
```

If get not find package error, you need this trick:

```
libpath = .libPaths()[1]
install.packages('yourpackage', lib = libpath)
```

Comment: Just try to do it step by step, if you have any problem i will help you. First is download usqlext\assembly\R\MRS.9.1.0.zip from datalake and execute r.exe localy

Comment: remember to unzip and run it on a machine with no r installed

Comment: I followed the steps explained above and I no longer get the errors that seems to be related to missing packages. Instead I get a new type of error related to directory information:

    Unhandled exception from user code: "Specified directory not found: 'D:\0436b1f1\bin\x64'"

I have added the following line sof code:

libpath = .libPaths()[1]
    install.packages('dplyr', lib = libpath)
    require(dplyr)

Comment: are you installing the package on a machine with no R installed?

Comment: remove the install.packages from your R Script, just use library('dplyr') to load the package and try a function of the package

Comment: Hi Jorge. I did as you explained and a normal R-script with only base R is still working. I can also run a script with library(dplyr) included. However as soon as I start using methods from dplyr I get errors like "Error: could not find function "%>%". I have tried both with and without libpath = .libPaths()[1] install.packages('dplyr', lib = libpath) with no difference in luck.

Comment: Seems the package are not correctly installed. Are you using a machine without R installed to install dplyr and recreate the zip?

Comment: I finally made it work with your method. However in the last attempt where it succeeded I made the MRS.9.1.0.zip with the extra library on my developer machine with R installed, so apparantly that was not an issue. Why it works now and failed the first times I do not know.

Comment: I tried it on 3 machines randomly which has no prior R installation but I could see same error all the time as  -  `"message":"An unhandled exception from user code has been reported when invoking the method 'Reduce' on the user type 'Extension.R.Reducer'","description":"Unhandled exception from user code: \"Specified directory not found: 'C:\\12af1737\\bin\\x64'\"\nThe details includes more information including any inner exceptions and the stack trace where the exception was raised."`

Answer (score 0):

The answer from "Jorge Ribeiro" works very well. But there are possibilities that, even after following the steps you may end up having an error as - .

```
 Unhandled exception from user code: "Specified directory not found:
 'D:\5827d493\bin\x64'". The details includes more information
 including any inner exceptions and the stack trace where the exception
 was raised.
```

In this scenario, following steps would resolve the issue. -

1. Download only the

   > /usqlext/assembly/R/MRS.9.1.0.zip

from azure datalake to
    local machine.

2. extract all the files the zipped (MRS.9.1.0.zip) file onto same location and execute R.exe on bin folder.
   Note: It does not matter if you download and unzip MRS.9.1.0.zip file onto machine with or without prior "R Installation". You can download & unzip on any machine.
3. Install all packages you want (with parameter dependencies = true &
   lib = libpath).

> libpath = "Path of the library folder under extracted files (i.e
>   unzipped library folder name)
>
> install.packages('yourpackage', dependencies = TRUE, lib = libpath)

4. Select All the files `(control + A)` and Zip them in the same location/folder again.

> Note : Always do select all and zip them back into same folder &
>   rename the zipped file (if needed as in name mentioned n RegsiterAll Assembly file).Otherwise, you'll always end up with error I mentioned above.

4. Upload and Replace the file on datalake by the one you've just now created.
5. Execute `RegisterAllAssemblies.USQL` and your libraries are available for use afterwards.

Comment: So the deciding difference being the lib = libpath in the install.packages line as I understand it. Thanks fo rthe input.